# how to make a calculator with a loop until I choose to break

Tags: python, calculator

I'm trying to build a calculator with a loop until I choose to break it or end it.
Can you please suggest?
Thank you in advance,
Max

```
new_operation = input("press enter to make a new operation or type the word exit to finish")

num1 = int(input("Enter a number: "))
op = input("Enter the operator: ")
num2 = int(input("Enter a second number: "))
while new_operation != ("no"):
    if op == ("+"):
        print (num1 + num2)
    elif op == ("-"):
        print (num1 - num2)
    elif op == ("*"):
        print (num1 * num2)
    elif op == ("/"):\
        print (num1 / num2)

else:
        print ("Invalid operation")
    new_operation = input("make a new operation")
```

Comment: Check your indentation.

Comment: Well if you want to be able to control when to break the while loop, you're gonna need an `input` line somewhere INSIDE the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks good, but need some tweak to make it "do while" loop kind of implementation.

```
while True:
    num1 = int(input("Enter a number: "))
    op = input("Enter the operator: ")
    num2 = int(input("Enter a second number: "))
    if op == ("+"):
        print (num1 + num2)
    elif op == ("-"):
        print (num1 - num2)
    elif op == ("*"):
        print (num1 * num2)
    elif op == ("/"):\
        print (num1 / num2)
    else:
        print ("Invalid operation")
    new_operation = input("press enter to make a new operation or type the word exit to finish")
    if(new_operation == ("no")):
        break
```

Comment: Thank you very much my brother, it is working now as I wanted it to work :)

Answer (score 0):

Some suggestions:

- Check your indentation, as commented above. Python is sensitive to that.
- Make sure your inputs and outputs are more consistent and useful. Your prompt says I should type `exit`, but your code requires them to type `no`...
- Your looping structure is a bit broken. This is to be expected for somebody new to coding. One of my favorites for this case is:

  ```
  print('Welcome to the calculator!')
  do_run = True
  while do_run: 
    ...
    do_run = input('Would you like to continue [y/n]: ')[0].lower() == 'y'
  ```